# Access currently logged in user in UserRepository in Sylius

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I would like to do something like this.

```yaml
sylius_backend_user_index:
    pattern: /
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.user:indexAction
        _sylius:
            template: SyliusWebBundle:Backend/User:index.html.twig
            method: createFilterPaginator
            arguments: [$criteria, $sorting, $deleted, @service_container]
```

I would like to access service_container in `createFilterPaginator` method. Can any one help me to sort out this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, no need for the whole service container, you need only `security.context`. I assume you have already extended the `UserRepository` so you can overwrite the `createFilterPaginator()` method and it is correctly configured as the `sylius.repository.user` service.

You have to add a simple setter to your respository:

```
class UserRepository extends BaseUserRepository
{
    protected $user;

    public setUserViaSecurityContext(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext)
    {
        $this->user = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
    }
}
```

Now you have to manipulate the service definition in a compiler pass

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\YourBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class ModifyRepositoryPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container
            ->findDefinition('sylius.repository.user')
            ->addMethodCall('setUserViaSecurityContext', array(
                new Reference('security.context'),
            ))
        ;
    }
}
```

And call this Compiler pass in your bundles file:

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\YourBundle;

use Acme\Bundle\YourBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ModifyRepositoryPass;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AcmeYourBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new ModifyRepositoryPass());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. but i have got an error "The service definition "sylius.repository.user" does not exist." when i add your given configuration in my bundles Extension class. can you please help me?

Comment: Damn it. I didn't test it, but the service exist, as you use it normaly. But it does not exist at the moment where you're building your bundle.. :(

Comment: Before inserting  `$container->findDefinition('sylius.repository.user')` in Extension class,
i tried with `container:debug` command at that time, i found service.
but after inserting code in Extension class as you me at that time  i got the same error. :(

Comment: It should work with a compiler pass, modified my answer.