# Symfony - Get security.token_storage in Sylius repositories

Tags: php, symfony4, sylius

I have tried to inject `security.token_storage` service via `CompilerPass`, I do not have errors and user is currently logged, however when I access the TokenStorage, `$tokenStorage->getToken()` I got a null response.

I checked these links to reference, but I cannot achieve to get a valid token.

[How to inject shared service from compiler pass in Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46116395/how-to-inject-shared-service-from-compiler-pass-in-symfony) and [Access currently logged in user in UserRepository in Sylius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012947/access-currently-logged-in-user-in-userrepository-in-sylius)

Do you an idea why it returns null response?

- Sylius version: 1.4 and Symfony 4.4

Bundle class:

```
   public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
   {
       parent::build($container);
       $container->addCompilerPass(new ModifyRepositoryPass());
   }
```

ModifyRepositoryPass class:

```
class ModifyRepositoryPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{

   public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
   {
       $container
           ->getDefinition('sylius.repository.order')
           ->addMethodCall('getTokenStorage', array(
               new Reference('security.token_storage')
           ));

    }
  }
```

Get token:

```
class OrderRepository extends BaseOrderRepository
{

    /** @var TokenStorageInterface */
    protected $tokenStorage;

    public function getTokenStorage(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function createListFilter()
    {

        $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()); //  NULL token
    }
```

Config.yml

```
sylius_order:
  resources:
    order:
      classes:
        repository: AppBundle\Repository\OrderRepository
         #method: getTokenStorage  also, I tried inject expression, but it does not work
         #arguments: ["tokenStorage", "expr:service('security.token_storage').getToken()"]
```

Comment: Null is returned when user logged out, are you sure about it? Did you checked that requests with Symfony Profiler Security tab?

Comment: The user is logged in, actually, if I retrieve the token from controller I get a valid token,but when I try to use compilerPass it is null.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is because tokenstorage is not populated at the compilerpass execution moment. Do you have another oportunity to handle it on another time period, for example built-in kernel event `kernel.request`?

By the way, did tried just to inject `\Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Context\CustomerContext` service into repository, without compilerpass?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in that case, do you know how can inject CustomerContext in my custom repository?, I added my  repository to the question

Comment: add  `CustomerContext` to repository contstructor and use in its methods. Constructor injection example https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#injecting-services-config-into-a-service

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I could not inject to repository construct function or use setter injection as we know it.

I tried several ways to retrieve user session and my last resort was overwrite the grid `sylius_admin_order` and use an expression:   `expr:service('security.token_storage').getToken()`

- `AdminBundle/Resources/config/grids/order.yml` overwrite: `vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/config/grids/order.yml`

```
  sylius_grid:
   grids:
    sylius_admin_order:
      driver:
        name: doctrine/orm
        options:
          class: "%sylius.model.order.class%"
          repository:
            method: createListQueryBuilder
            arguments:
              usernamePasswordToken: "expr:service('security.token_storage').getToken()"
             .......
```

- OrderRepository:

```
    class OrderRepository extends BaseOrderRepository
    {

     /**
     * @param UsernamePasswordToken|null $usernamePasswordToken
     * @return QueryBuilder
     */
    public function createListQueryBuilder($usernamePasswordToken = null): QueryBuilder
    {
      $user = $usernamePasswordToken->getUser();
```